# Can't create repo for ElasticSearch snapshot

Tags: elasticsearch, backup, snapshot

I'm trying to create a backup repo for my ElasticSearch snapshot.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/backup' -d '{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "/home/admin/dumps/elasticsearch",
    "compress": true
  }
}'
```

The issue I obtained is:

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"repository_exception","reason":"[backup]
>   failed to create repository"}],...

I'm quite sure it's a right/user problem on my directory.

I tried:

```
chmod 777 /home/admin/dumps/elasticsearch
```

Actually the repo rights are:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 admin admin 4096 Jan  6 14:39 elasticsearch
```

But I have the same issue.

I also tried the curl using sudo (same issue).

Well, I'm lost now. ;-)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you add `path.repo: ["/home/admin/dumps/elasticsearch"]` to `elasticsearch.yml` file?

Comment: No ! Just added. Seems to work after ES restarting. Thanks !

Comment: @ChintanShah25 Add that as the answer for an upvote and hopefully they'll also accept it!

Comment: @pickypg I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 7):

You first have to mount your shared filesystem to the same location on all the nodes, so add `path.repo: ["/home/admin/dumps/elasticsearch"]` to `elasticsearch.yml`

From the [Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html)

> In order to register the shared file system repository it is necessary
>   to mount the same shared filesystem to the same location on all master
>   and data nodes. This location (or one of its parent directories) has
>   to be registered in the path.repo setting on all master and data
>   nodes.

Then You need to restart all your nodes.

Comment: Thanks again for this sharing and the answer !